# awk two columns into a bash for loop

Tags: bash, awk

Please help!

I have a little bit of a time sensitive issue here and so I am turning to Stackoverflow in the hope that I can get a fairly quick reply. I'm not a bash expert, especially when having to think quickly. I am trying to awk in two columns from a user database into an OpenStack API. The database (flat file I created) is really simple. It looks something like this:

```
| ID | username | True |
```

The database is pretty large so I am trying to loop through this. Here is the command I am trying to run:

```
for user in $(cat users.txt); do keystone user-role-add --user $user --role blah --tenant $tenant; done
```

This works great assuming users.txt list had a single username on each line.

I need to modify this command to pull the username out of users.txt for $user and also pull the corresponding ID out of users.txt for $tenant

*** SOLUTION ***

```
while read line;do
  tenant=$(echo $line|awk '{print $2}')
  user=$(echo $line|awk '{print $4}')
  keystone user-role-add --user $user --role blah --tenant $tenant
done <users.txt
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Does the database file actually have vertical bars between columns? If not, show an actual row.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it looks like

Comment: Unrelated to the problem directly but read [Don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) then [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: For example I used this to separate out the columns. Just not very good with awk. Need to tie the two concepts together. awk '{print $'4'}' < userlist.txt > output.txt

Comment: Yes thank you Etan. This is a quick and dirty solution. This is essentially working so far. Dont want to reinvent the wheel here, but thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like...

```
while read line;do
  id=$(echo $line|awk '{print $2}')
  username=$(echo $line|awk '{print $4}')
  bool=$(echo $line|awk '{print $6}')
  # do other
  # action here
done <users.txt
```

Comment: I will post the actual solution above. Needed a slight modification to make everything work. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This way avoids using awk, it shoud be more optimized:

```
  while read id username tenant; do
      echo "---DEBUG --- id=${id} username=${username} tenant=${tenant}"
      # do other action here
      # calling variables as in DEBUG line above
  done <users.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F' *[|] *' \
    '{print "keystone user-role-add --user \47" $3 "\47 --role blah --tenant \47" $2 "\47"}' users.txt \
| bash
```

Explanation line by line:

1. Pass the file through `awk` using pipe with zero or more leading/trailing spaces as a delimiter.
2. For each line of file `users.txt` print the required command as string. `$2` and `$3` mean second and third field from delimited file. `\47` will be interpolated to a single quote in the output, in case we have spaces in values.
3. Pipe the printed commands from the previous step to `bash` for execution.